# C# Send Mail using SMTP? with a different from email address

Tags: c#, android, smtp

I know this has been covered a million times, but I just can't find what I'm looking for... (maybe its not out there)

First of all, I've tried the gmail smtp route... yes it works... but I have an issue with this situation... I've made an Android app in C#/making an app, it basically logs jobs to our support email address which then goes through and logs a job in our support software. I really really really want the app to basically carry through whatever is in the 'email address' text box as the from address in the email. The reason the gmail solution won't work for me properly is I'll never know all of the possible email addresses to populate the list so they'll never work properly... I'm looking for a good old-skool smtp server out there somewhere that allows this to happen? I know everyone is scared about the big bad SPAM word but its not spamming I'm heading for, this is a legit app that will be used by our technicians out in the field.

It's a proof of concept app at the moment so I can't go asking for servers to be turned into SMTP servers and allowed out onto the net so they can be seen etc otherwise we could probably do it that way and keep it in house... But atleast for now, I'm looking for a solution to do it free if that exists anymore? :-S

Comment: Searching for open SMTP relay, configuring local SMTP server, or searching for SMTP server software (i.e. IIS on Windows) is not in scope for SO.

Comment: Users should be willing to setup their own email on the mobile device if they want automated support.

Comment: Not fair branding me as one of those types of people... I assure you this is legit... I just don't get it sometimes... I understand why you wouldn't be able to do it and publicly anounce it etc but all you had to say was that, not in the way ou have done... shocking really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a simple, straightforward and easily maintainable mail service, try this:

Configure a windows server with a virtual SMTP server on it. Accept connections only from localhost. Add a webservice to the server that accepts To, From, Body, Subject and a form of authentication. Expose that webservice to the web via its url, eg: http://yourdomain.com/emailwebservice

When your app needs to send an email, it sends it to the webservice with parameters specified. The webservice in turn generates an email and sends it to the local virtual smtp server. The virtual smtp server can then send to the recipient(s).

The good about this:

- You can have authentication to prevent unauthorized emails from being
  sent through your webservice
- More secure than having a publicly-exposed smtp server
- Can implement additional logic as needed at the webservice level
- uses common http(s) protocol that most networks will not block

The bad about this:

- an additional failure point - the webservice
- If webservice is down, messages will not be received and stored